# How to make products show on homepage randomly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to make products show on homepage in a random manner.

Here's my homepage controller codes.

please help

Answer (score 1):

In order to get random ordered products, use:

```php
$products = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(20)->get();
```